# Ignore trailing slash in Nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have a nginx configuration like below:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location @publicsite {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Connection close;
        proxy_pass https://public-site.com$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @publicsite;
    }

    //other locations...
}
```

With this configuration, when I try to access `www.example.com/pricing/` it works like expected. But when I try to access `www.example.com/pricing` it works like `https://public-site.com/pricing/`.

Is there a way to escape from this real-domain redirection?

Output:

```
www.example.com/pricing/ => www.example.com/pricing/
www.example.com/pricing => https://public-site.com/pricing/
```

Expected:

```
www.example.com/pricing/ => www.example.com/pricing/
www.example.com/pricing => www.example.com/pricing/
```

Comment: Your configuration should work as you expected. Isn't it an `https://public-site.com` that issues `/pricing` -> `https://public-site.com/pricing/` redirection? You can try `proxy_redirect https://public-site.com/ /;` in your `location @publicsite { ... }` block.

Comment: @IvanShatsky the problem is that I should never see `public-site` int the url but in this case `www.example.com/pricing => https://public-site.com/pricing/`, I see it.

Comment: `proxy_set_header Host public-site.com;` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed my problem with

```
proxy_set_header Host public-site.com;
```